# Self healing error handling in RxJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I'm new to RxJS.

I have a promised base HTTP client. It has a *login()* method that fetches a token from the server and stores it internally to be used by other methods.

When token expires, server will respond with **401** HTTP error, in which case, I want to call *login()* again and retry the request. Also, retry for other types of errors.

I'm not sure how to model that in RxJS, I've got something working but I'm hoping there's a better way to do it.

(*this is inside a decorator that's applied to all auth requiring methods*, here **wrappedFunc**)

```
        return interval(100)
            .pipe(
                startWith(0),
                switchMap(() => {
                    return wrappedFunc.apply(this, args)
                }),
                retryWhen(errors$ => errors$.pipe(
                    switchMap((error) => {
                        if (error.response.status === 401) {
                            return this.login()
                        } else {
                            return of(error)
                        }
                    }),
                    scan((attempts, currentError) => {
                        if (attempts > 5) {
                            throw currentError
                        }
                        return attempts + 1
                    }, 0),
                )),
                first()
            )
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this kind of error handling in RxJS?

Comment: Why `interval(100)`? Is this to delay **wrappedFunc** call?

Comment: Opps! This is to retry every 100ms, I was under the impression that it would emit immediately and then wait 100ms and emit again, but looking at the docs it seems I was wrong! :)  Adding startWith(0) seems to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interval(100)` is emitting every 100ms and `switchMap` will cancel ongoing subscription and resubscribe so if the `wrappedFunc` call takes more than 100ms it will never "happen" - it will try to make the call again and again.

I think you want something more along these lines:

```
return defer(() => wrappedFunc.apply(this, args))
  .pipe(
    retryWhen(errors$ => errors$.pipe(
      switchMap((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          return this.login()
        } else {
          return of(error)
        }
      }),
      scan((attempts, currentError) => {
        if (attempts > 5) {
          throw currentError
        }
        return attempts + 1
      }, 0),
      delay(100),
    ))
  );
```

The `defer` here serves as a wrapper so `wrappedFunc` can return either Promise or Observable and the `delay` is for delaying the retry.